# Get string from NSArray, saved using NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save 2 strings into an array using NSUserDefaults, but when I want to get the strings there are some problems.

This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)closeSettingsView:(id)sender {


NSArray *saveStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"%@", @"%@", yourNameTextField.text, customPhraseTextField.text, nil];
NSUserDefaults *defaultsFields = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaultsFields setObject:saveStrings forKey:@"savedStrings"];
[defaultsFields synchronize];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSUserDefaults *defaultsFields = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *loadStrings = [defaultsFields stringArrayForKey:@"savedStrings"];

NSString *nameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [loadStrings objectAtIndex:0]];
NSString *phraseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [loadStrings objectAtIndex:1]];

NSLog(@"%@", nameString);
NSLog(@"%@", phraseString);


}
```

This is my log:

```
2013-07-09 02:59:31.639 Alarm Pro[219:60b] %@
2013-07-09 02:59:31.642 Alarm Pro[219:60b] %@
```

What can I do to correctly read the strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding the @"%@" strings twice at the beginning of the array with:

```
NSArray *saveStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"%@", @"%@", yourNameTextField.text, customPhraseTextField.text, nil];
```

Insert just the variables with:

```
NSArray *saveStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:yourNameTextField.text, customPhraseTextField.text, nil];
```

With the code you have, the array has 4 objects, the first and second of which are the strings @"%@" and @"%@" again. Thus, when you call [loadStrings objectAtIndex:0] and [loadStrings objectAtIndex:1], the output is those first two strings, @"%@" and @"%@".

In other words, you're not first defining the formats of the objects and then passing the variables containing the strings with initWithObjects: but rather just the objects themselves, with no preceding formats.

Answer (score 2):

Your strings are read correctly, it's just you're saving the wrong data.

```
NSArray *saveStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"%@", @"%@", yourNameTextField.text, customPhraseTextField.text, nil];
```

This creates an array with 4 elements. First two of them are @"%@", so when you take objectAtIndex 0 and 1, it correctly returns @"%@" in both cases.

You need to rewrite your save code a little:

```
NSArray *saveStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:yourNameTextField.text, customPhraseTextField.text, nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *str1=[textbox1.text];
NSString *str2=[textbox2.text];
NSArray *arr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:str1,str2, nil];

then use  NSUserDefaults
```

Answer (score 1):

The other responses are correct.
You can also use the new Obj-C syntax to make it more readable.

```
NSArray *saveStrings = @[yourNameTextField.text, customPhraseTextField.text];
```

If you do want to actually format the string, I would split it on multiple lines. i.e.:

```
NSString *entry1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sir %@", yourNameTextField.text];
NSArray *saveStrings = @[entry1, customPhraseTextField.text];
```